# Delete a row where its primary key is closest to X

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, sqlite

**I am attempting to delete a row, whose primary key(column name=version) for example is 4.002000000000001. So I give say the statement:**

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE version=4.002;
```

**Now right now this wont work, because theres no row that has a version equal to 4.002, only a row with a version equal to 4.002000000000001.** *Please dont ask why I dont store the version as 4.002 in the DB because I am trying to do so by making the column type DECIMAL(5,3) but it still stores a double from Java as 4.002000000000001. And please dont ask why I dont say "...WHERE version=4.002000000000001;" because right now I have no control over how java formats it doubles(even using DecimalFormat class) when I create a statement using JDBC.*

So is there a way to round down(floor function) in SQLite3? So then I can say "delete the row whose FLOOR(version) is equal to 4.002?

I am a C++ programmer (using Java to query an SQL database, please dont ask why :P) who is not proficient with complex SQL queries, so would this be correct for what I want to do:

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE ROUND(version, 0.5)=4.002;
```

Comment: Good heavens.  A decimal PK mapped to a `double`.  That is...quite fraught.

Comment: Should I use a different Java data type? Float? Maybe String? I know having a SQL decimal primary key is bad, but I am updating a large existing project & its better to work within the framework than redesign & start again.

Comment: I agree with @Kirk .. you should probably step back, take a few deep breaths, and ask yourself why on earth you want to have a non-integer as primary key.

Comment: And after those deep breaths, go ahead and go back through your old questions and accept some answers.

Comment: This is like asking in a car forum "please tell me how to install a second gas pedal to make my car going faster, don't ask me why I chose this method to make my car going faster".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you do?

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE version > 4.002 - 1e-4 AND version < 4.002 + 1e-4
```

or

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE version > 4.0015 AND version < 4.0025
```

Answer (score 5):

> And please dont ask why I dont say "...WHERE version=4.002000000000001;" because right now I have no control over how java formats it doubles(even using DecimalFormat class)

I won't.

But I will ask why you are using `double` to store a version number.

Machine floating point types (base 2) do not hold exact decimal numbers.  But version number strings are exact.  You would be better off treating version "numbers" as one of the following, depending on your version numbering scheme:

- Scaled integers; e.g. `4.002` is `4002` divided by `1000`.  You probably don't need to store the scaling factor explicitly.
- Tuples or arrays of integers; e.g. `4.002` is `{4,2}`.  This allows version numbers like `4.003.005` to be represented as `{4,3,5}` etcetera.
- Character strings constrained by a pattern; e.g. `4.002` is a string that matches the regex `"\d+\.\d\d\d"`.  This allows version strings with non-numeric parts.

Choose one of those and you won't have to worry about the fundamental inexact nature of floating point types, in memory or in the database.

---

Oh, and by the way the [`DecimalFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class *does* let you control the number of digits after the decimal place when you format a number.  You can specify this using a pattern or by calling [`setMaximumFractionDigits`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setMaximumFractionDigits%28int%29)

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM tbl WHERE abs(version-4.002)<.0001
```

if you want to remove all versions in an epsilon boundary of .0001